# Prove that the solution of $y'+y=\arctan(e^x), y(0)=2$ admits horizontal asymptote.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Let us consider the Cauchy problem: 
$$y'+y=\arctan(e^x),\ \ \ \ y(0)=2$$ 
Prove that the function $y(x)$ admits horizontal asymptote without solving the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll prove a more general case, instead. If $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)+f'(x)=l$, then:

$$\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=l\\
&\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f'(x)=0
\end{align}$$

Suppose we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)+f'(x)=l$$

Then we have $$e^x(f(x)+f'(x))\approx_{x\rightarrow +\infty} le^x $$
$$(e^xf(x))'\approx_{x\rightarrow +\infty} le^x=(le^x)'$$
Since $x\rightarrow le^x$ is positive and its integral diverges at $+\infty$, then
$$e^xf(x)\approx_{x\rightarrow +\infty} le^x \tag{justification at the bottom}$$

Therefore $$f(x)\approx_{x\rightarrow +\infty} l $$

So, finally we have:

$$\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=l\\
&\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f'(x)=0
\end{align}$$

---

In your example, we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} y+y'=\pi/2$

Therefore

$$\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}y=\pi/2\\
&\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}y'=0 
\end{align}$$

and $y$ has an horizontal asymptote.

---

**Justification:**

Suppose we have two functions $f,g\in \mathcal C^1$ such that $g'$ is non-negative, and $g(x)$ tends to $+\infty$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$ and $$f'(x)\approx_{x\rightarrow +\infty} g'(x) $$
i.e $$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists x_0\in \Bbb R \text{ s.t } x\geq x_0\implies |f'(x)-g'(x)|\leq \varepsilon g'(x) $$

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then $\exists x_0\in \Bbb R \text{ s.t } x\geq x_0\implies |f'(x)-g'(x)|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} g'(x)$

We have for $x\geq x_0$
$$\begin{align}
|f(x)-g(x)|&=\left|f(0)-g(0)+\int_{0}^x (f'(t)-g'(t))dt\right| \\
&=\left|f(0)-g(0)+\int_0^{x_0} (f'(t)-g'(t))dt + \int_{x_0}^x (f'(t)-g'(t))dt\right|\\
&\leq \left|f(0)-g(0)+\int_0^{x_0} (f'(t)-g'(t))dt\right| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\int_{x_0}^x g'(t)dt\\
&\leq \varepsilon g(x)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\left|f(0)-g(0)+\int_0^{x_0} (f'(t)-g'(t))dt\right|-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}g(x_0)}{\varepsilon g(x)}\right)
\end{align}$$

Since $\frac{1}{g(x)}\rightarrow 0$, then $\exists x_1\in \Bbb R: x\geq x_1\implies \left|\frac{\left|f(0)-g(0)+\int_0^{x_0} (f'(t)-g'(t))dt\right|-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}g(x_0)}{\varepsilon}\right|\frac{1}{g(x)}\leq \frac12$

So for $x\geq\max(x_0,x_1)=x_2$, we have:

$$|f(x)-g(x)|\leq \varepsilon g(x) $$
Therefore

$$f(x)\approx_{x\rightarrow +\infty}g(x) $$

Comment: Hm, proof is perhaps a strong word for this. Can you make the argument more rigorous?

Comment: Agree with Simon.  Shows promise, though.  Suggest you keep at it for a nice, complete result.  ***Endorsed!!!*** Cheers!

Comment: @SimonS Hm, I don't really understand what's the problem with the argument.

Comment: @Farnight It would be better if you produced a proof with $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ instead of $\approx$ in order to quantify the error at the limit (and to show that it tends to zero).

Comment: @Nicolas I just added a justification at the bottom. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Farnight It is better. Two points : 1) You need to argue why you can apply the fundamental theorem of the Analysis (to be differentiable is not enough ; an argument of smoothness or countability of the points where the function is not differentiable is required) ; 2) One of your assumptions was $\lim g'(x)=+\infty$, but you used that $\lim g(x)=+\infty$, so you need to precise or fix something here ?

Comment: @Farnight Sorry it is the fundamental theorem of calculus, which states that $\int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\mathrm{d}x=f(b)-f(a)$ under some conditions.$

Comment: @Nicolas For the first part, we can add the assumption that $f,g \in \mathcal C^1$, which is satisfied by the example. For the second, it was just a mistake. It's fixed now.

Comment: @Farnight Ok, it is good now. Nice job! +1

Comment: @Nicolas This was the hardest I've had to work for a +1 so far. :P